# Visual Studio Code: is there a way to define global keybindings that apply to all profiles?

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

I recently started using Profiles in VS Code and it's been great for the most part, but I can't find a way to define custom keybindings that apply globally to all profiles. Here's what I've been able to figure out:

1. User keybindings are stored in `Code/User/keybindings.json`.
2. Profile keybindings are stored in `Code/User/profiles/<profile ID>/keybindings.json`.
3. If I add/edit a keybinding through the GUI (`⌘K ⌘S`) it will save to the Profile, not the User, and it won't be available in other profiles.
4. If I add/edit a keybinding through `User/keybindings.json` it is not available in any profiles except the Default profile.

Not sure if this is a bug or a feature, but is there a way to define global keybindings when using Profiles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at `Partial Profiles` in Insiders now and Stable v1.81 early August 2023.

> #### Support for Partial Profiles
>
> You can now create a profile in which you can customize only a subset
> of configurations (Settings, Keyboard Shortcuts, Snippets, Tasks &
> Extensions). For example, you can create a Profile with all
> configurations except for Keyboard Shortcuts, and VS Code will apply
> the keyboard shortcuts from the Default Profile when this Profile is
> active. Following picture shows the UI for creating such a Profile.

[image: partial profiles image]

> You can also create a partial profile by copying from Profile
> Templates or from an existing Profile using the dropdown menu which is
> shown in the following picture.

From my testing, if you create a profile without the Keyboard Shortcuts selected, any shortcuts you create in the Default Profile will be available in your new profile. And a shortcut you create while your new profile is active will be available in the Default profile but apparently NOT in other profiles created before the option to make a "partial profile".

This may be a better route for you to modify any existing profiles:

> You can also configure an existing Profile to use configurations from
> the Default Profile by editing the Profile like shown in the following
> picture.
>
> [same image as above]
>
> When exporting such a profile you can choose to export only the
> configurations that are customized in the Profile or also includes the
> configurations from the Default Profile. The following picture shows
> the UI for exporting a Profile.

Comment: Thanks! I haven't tried this out yet but looks like it'll work great.